# in Web Api Validate field is exactly 15 characters but the field in not required

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

Is there a way in data attributes to say if the field is not null then it must be a certain length?

I have

```
 <StringLength(15, MinimumLength:=15, ErrorMessage:="RequisitonNumber must be exactly 15 characters. ")>
    Public Property RequisitonNumber() As String
        Get
            Return m_RequisitonNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_RequisitonNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_RequisitonNumber As String
```

this works fine when a value is submitted but this is not a required field so when it is left empty the validation error is being thrown.